# magento : get list of category with api

Tags: php, category, api, category-tree

i want to get list of category and subcategory (name of category) in magento , i use this API : catalogCategoryInfo (SOAP V2) . i try to get Names of direct child categories but it return id of direct child ! my question is how can i get name of category child ? 
 [API Link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.info.html)

Answer (score 4):

`catalogCategoryInfo` method returns full information about one category. But ids are the only information about its child categories.

Try to use [`catalogCategoryTree`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.tree.html) method instead. It will return you category information tree, with all children names.